# Тире во второй части сложного предложения

Tags: пунктуация

**Герой конца не знает, а рассказчик знает.**

Во второй части предложения нужно тире?

Answer (score 1):

Да, противопоставление частей можно подчеркнуть с помощью тире:

Герой не знает конца, а рассказчик – знает.

Comment: а  разве тут нет обязательного правила постановки тире по той причине, что вторая часть предложения неполная?

Answer (score 1):

Постановка тире зависит от интонационного членения предложения.

1) Вы логически выделяете слова *знает* и *не знает*: **Герой не знАет конца, а рассказчик знАет (конец).** Этот вариант соответствует интонации полного предложения.

1) Вы логически выделяете слова *герой* и *рассказчик:* **ГерОй //не знает конца, а расскАзчик – знает.** Это тире авторское, интонационное, оно ставится при обозначении параллельной интонации.

Comment: а разве тут нет обязательного правила постановки тире по той причине, что вторая часть предложения неполная?

Answer (score 0):

Тире необходимо, так как имеет место *неполное предложение*, а точнее часть сложносочинённого предложения:

> Герой конца не знает, а рассказчик *[этот конец]* знает.
>
> ↓
>
> Герой конца не знает, а рассказчик — знает.